# C++ compiler, force pass by reference

Tags: c++, reference, parameter-passing, default

Is it possible to set as default a C++ compiler to interpret all parameter passing as being by-reference defining a new modifier to specify that you need a passage by copy.

Programming I found that only rerely I need to pass data by copy so, at least for me, would be much more effective to have "reference by default"

Comment: I do not think this is a pre-defined flag in any c++ compiler. You could implement it yourself (i.e. as a clang compiler-pass). But it would probably break many libraries, even the standard library

Comment: No, because otherwise it wouldn't be a C++ compiler.

Comment: There is no such feature or flag in gcc. I am not sure about other compilers, but no compiler would implement this. It can create confusions and readability issue.

Comment: Oh man are you passing ints by reference too? That's nuts.

Comment: @Pubby No, usually I convert int to String then I pass those.
Seriously: almost all the data I pass are objects, its really uncommon to have something to pass that is not an object.

Anyway adding a modifier will keep old code compatible with newer compilers (prepended & would be ignored), will just be newer code, in sections where copy is used, to being modified. Or just making this feature available as preprocessor directive would be enough. I think this feature will improve overall code efficiency (copying works the same but has major overhead)

Comment: As an aside: [object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object) means something rather specific in C++, and a reference is explicitly not an object.

Comment: You could just use a framework like Qt and all its types. They are for the most part copy-on-write. Or you can write your own CoW types. That seems a lot better than trying to change the Language. Even changing to Java or C# seems like a more sane "solution" to this "problem".

Answer (score 3):

Not only there isn't such a feature, **there can never be one**. Doing so would make well-defined programs ill-formed or worst, having Undefined Behaviour.

Consider this simple well-formed program:

```
struct X {};

auto bar(X x) -> decltype(x)
{
    return x;
}

auto test()
{
    bar(X{});
}
```

How would you transform it? There is no way to make `bar` take reference and not change the semantics of the program or make it UB

If you make `bar` take l-value reference then it can't accept a temporary:

```
struct X {};

auto bar(X& x) -> decltype(x)
{
    return x;
}

auto test()
{
    bar(X{});
}
```

> ```
> <source>:12:5: error: no matching function for call to 'bar'
>
>     bar(X{});
>
>     ^~~
>
> <source>:4:6: note: candidate function not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument
>
> auto bar(X& x) -> decltype(x)
>
>      ^
>
> 1 error generated.
> ```

If you make it take an r-value reference then you cannot return it without further modifications:

```
struct X {};

auto bar(X&& x) -> decltype(x)
{
    return x;
}

auto test()
{
    bar(X{});
}
```

> ```
> <source>:6:12: error: rvalue reference to type 'X' cannot bind to lvalue of type 'X'
>
>     return x;
>
>            ^
>
> 1 error generated.
> ```

Ok, you can solve this particular problem by moving the parameter. But that is well beyond what you initially set to change. Nevertheless, for the sake of the argument let's say you do, or that the original program was already doing it:

```
#include <utility>

struct X { };

auto bar(X&& x) -> decltype(x)
{
    return std::move(x);
}

auto test()
{
    bar(X{});
}
```

This finally indeed compiles. But do you see the problem? You return a reference to an expired object, you return a dangling reference:

```
// before

#include <utility>

struct X { auto foo() const {} };

auto bar(X x) -> decltype(x) // bar returns a prvalue
{
    return x;
    // or
    // return std::move(x); // redundant, but valid and equivalent
}

auto test()
{
    const X& xr = bar(X{}); // xr prolongs the lifetime of the temporary returned by `bar`

    xr.foo(); // OK, no problem
}
```

```
// after

#include <utility>

struct X { auto foo() const {} };

auto bar(X&& x) -> decltype(x) // now bar returns an xvalue
{
    return std::move(x);
}

auto test()
{
    const X& xr = bar(X{}); // xr cannot prolong the life of an xvalue
    // the temporary objects created as part of calling `bar` is now expired
    // and xr references it
    // any attempt to use xr results in UB

    xr.foo(); // Undefined Behaviour
}
```

There is no way to do what you want to do.

The burden is on you, the programmer: if you need values write values, if you need references write references. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

No.

I haven't heard of any compiler having this feature.